# How does one handle sub categories while model building?

Tags: correlation, credit-scoring

I'm building a classification model for predicting if someone would be a loan defaulter or not. Among the other 45 features, I have two features, they represent grade assigned by the bank to the individual. One feature is a sub-category of other. However, they might be highly correlated but I think removing any one of them will be a loss of information as if I remove the main category column each subcategory in the subcategory column will be treated individually and If I remove the subcategory column I would lose on some information. How do I handle it? Or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: The answer might depend on what analysis you intend to do ...

Comment: I'll be building a classification model where there are 45 features, these two are amongst them. Can I leave them as they are?

Comment: Please include new information as an edit to the post! What does this grade represent? An exam grade? if so, ordinal. Something else?

Comment: added more information

Comment: You need to explain in **detail** what that grade system is! Ordinal? What is the meaning of the grades? What is the meaning of the subgrades? Without that we can only guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, I wouldn't use either.

If this model is  to be used for loan origination purposes, I would exclude both variables (`grade` and `sub_grade`) since they won't be available at the time of assessment. This is because the grade (and subgrade) are assigned AFTER a loan has originated. In industry, the grade represents a mapping of the probability of default ($PD$) to a 'rating band'. For example, if your $PD$ is in $(0.1\%, 0.2\%]$, you'll be mapped to rating grade A2. This means grade is a proxy for the response.

If this model is to be used for modelling expected losses or capital requirements, I also wouldn't use either predictor. This is because the grade will be a proxy for the response (since it's a mapping of $PD$).

Ignoring what I said above, and assuming you did go ahead and try a build a model with these predictors then you should keep the following in mind.

- Assuming the grades are A to E, and within each grade you can have five subgrades, then this means the `sub_grade` column would have at least 25 different levels (A1, A2, ..., E5).
- If you just pump `sub_grade` through a logistic regression (for example), you would end up with 24 predictors straight away (since one grade would be absorbed into the intercept). In my opinion, you're just wasting degrees of freedom and producing an overly complex model for (probably) only a small amount of gain.
- If you just used only the `grade` column, you'd only have 4 predictors in the model. This model is much simpler and is much easier to interpret, which is extremely important when building models for credit scoring.

Comment: assuming, I went ahead and try to build model, You're saying using grade would be preferable over using sub-grade?

Comment: Correct. In my opinion, sub-grade has too many levels to be easily interpreted. You can look at information value (IV), which is a univariate measure of predictive power, for both grade and sub-grade. If sub-grade only gives slightly more bang for buck, there's not really any use for it since it overly complicates your model.